# I want to remove an array item when generated check box checked

Tags: javascript

I made a todolist which is taking value from input and add an item from array so when the given value shown in page i want to remove an item form array whn checkbox checked.

Html part :

```
<input type="text" id="field" placeholder="Type name" />
<button type="submit" onclick="insertitem()">Submit</button>
<p id="para"></p>
```

javascript part:

```
var list = [];
var input;
function insertitem() {
    input = document.getElementById('field').value;
    list.push(input);
    DisplayItem(list);
    document.getElementById('field').value='';

}
function DisplayItem(data) {
    var contain = document.getElementById('para');
    contain.innerHTML='';
    for ( var i in data) {
        contain.innerHTML +="<div><input id='box' onClick='remove()' type='checkbox' /><label>" + data[i] + "</label></div>";
    }
}
function remove() {
    var check = document.getElementById('box').value;
    for ( var i in list) {
        if (list[i]!= check) {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For an `<input type='checkbox'>` you'll need to use `.checked` in Javascript, which will return a boolean, not `.value`. Also, you'll want to wrap your `<label>` tag around the whole `<input>` tag. Just a couple pointers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove a particular element from an array in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767325/how-to-remove-a-particular-element-from-an-array-in-javascript)

Comment: A couple more pointers on your actual problem:  Look up how to add event handlers to dynamically created elements. Also look up event delegation.

Comment: Just loop through all elements of list and remove checked element using splice method

Comment: Adding more to @Andrew 's comment: You are creating multiple elements with duplicate Id which is invalid html. In remove function `check` will return first element always

Comment: can you please edit my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this with pure javascript :

> 1. **[Array.splice](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp)** and **[Array.indexof()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof_array.asp)**
> 2. Add with checkbox inside the label tag.
> 3. And click event change with `remove(this)`.Then easly find the label
>      text and match with `list array`.

```
contain.innerHTML +="<div><label><input id='box' onClick='remove(this)' type='checkbox' />" + data[i] + 
              "</label></div>";
        }
```

```js
var list = [];
var input;
function insertitem() {
    input = document.getElementById('field').value;
    list.push(input);
    DisplayItem(list);
    document.getElementById('field').value='';

}
function DisplayItem(data) {
    var contain = document.getElementById('para');
    contain.innerHTML='';
    for ( var i in data) {
        contain.innerHTML +="<div><label><input id='box' onClick='remove(this)' type='checkbox' />" + data[i] + 
          "</label></div>";
    }
}
function remove(that) {
    var check = that.parentElement.textContent;
  //that.remove() if you need remove clicked box
    for ( var i in list) {
        if (list[i] == check) {
              list.splice(list.indexOf(check),1);
        }
    }
  console.log(list)
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="field" placeholder="Type name" />
<button type="submit" onclick="insertitem()">Submit</button>
<p id="para"></p>
```

Comment: Have you tested your code? Remove will not work. For dynamic elements events are binded separately.

Comment: @anu  see the snippet its working.Is remove the array value with selected check box label text

Comment: My bad. I read the question wrong, I thought OP wants to remove the checkbox itself.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var list = [];
var input;
function insertitem() {
    input = document.getElementById('field').value;
    list.push(input);
    DisplayItem(list);
    document.getElementById('field').value='';

}
function DisplayItem(data) {
    var contain = document.getElementById('para');
    contain.innerHTML='';
    for ( var i in data) {
        contain.innerHTML +="<div id='remove" + i + "'><label for='box" + i + "'><input id='box" + i + "' onClick='remove(" + i + ")' type='checkbox' />" + data[i] + "</label></div>";
    }
}
function remove(targetId) {
    var check = document.getElementById('box' + targetId).checked;
    if(check){
      console.log('Remove box' + targetId);
      document.getElementById('remove' + targetId).innerHTML='';
    }
}
```

```html
  <input type="text" id="field" placeholder="Type name" />
  <button type="submit" onclick="insertitem()">Submit</button>
  <p id="para"></p>
```

I just modified your JavaScript to pass an ID with a number to set each label apart from each other..